# dynamically pass strings as atoms ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to automate the following style of definition:

```
private

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

By passing the atoms as strings:

```
def generator(model_name, params)
  params.require(model_name).permit(params)
end
```

Can this be done in Ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely!  Ruby is a very dynamic language

You can do something like this:

```
def generator(model)
  name = model.class.name.to_s.underscore
  define_method "#{name}_params" do
    params.require(name).permit(model.attributes.keys - [model.class.primary_key])
  end
end
```

Let me know if that works for you,
I'd recommend extracting this into a mixin

Comment: The ability to pass parameters through does not make the language dynamic :) Also, this is a **very bad** advise, since it silently permits all the attributes defined on the model (including, you know, `:id` etc.)

Comment: And `model.attributes.keys` will not give you nested parameters either.

Comment: @mudasobwa There. Happy?